# How to write unittests for HTML tags

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to figure out how to create unittest for figuring out html tags in a document or a set of documents. I was thinking of using Beautifulsoup to pull tags out but I have a hard time to create a unittest with both. I've tried just pulling out the unittest and making it equal to a tag but it didn't seem to work with asking that there's only one html tag for opening and closing the document (What I wanted it to test).

Comment: Can I get Input HTML content and what we want to pull from the Input HTML content then what is structure of new Output file? Can you update question or email me vivekbsable@gmail.com details.

Comment: for instance I'd like to pull that:                                                        <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>My First Heading</h1>

<p>My first paragraph.</p>

</body>
</html>  has exactly these tags: the <html> and the </html>

Comment: not getting. Can you shear Input HTML and respect Output on my email vivekbsable@gmail.com??